# How to load data from react to index.html

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a requirement where I have to load some data from React to an input field `index.html`. I have created:

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<input type="text" id="input" name="fInput">
```

and in `index.js` I am trying to access it and assign a value to it.

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
const myInput = document.getElementById("input");
myInput.value= "test";
```

But it is not working, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please use react as intended or don't use it at all

Comment: what is wrong in trying out and learning the things.

Comment: Everything, you didn't use react at all https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `<script>` tag in `index.html` to import `index.js`